# deep learning for operations researchers

Tags: deep-learning

I have some basic knowledge about deep learning methods (fully connected and convolutional NNs). I would like to expand my knowledge of deep learning which could be beneficial for an operations researcher. What resource/book would you suggest for reading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the book that I used for my class at VT:
https://www.deeplearningbook.org/

This is another book that was recommended there:
https://d2l.ai/

This book on online learning is also useful:
[https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/papers/OLsurvey.pdf](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Eshais/papers/OLsurvey.pdf)
"Online Learning and Online Convex Optimization" by Shai Shalev-Shwartz.

Some papers I found helpful from Van Hentenryck:
"Fast Approximations for Job Shop Scheduling: A Lagrangian Dual Deep Learning Method",
"Predicting AC Optimal Power Flows: Combining Deep Learning and Lagrangian Dual Methods".

Also, this paper is helpful: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.03341.pdf "Stable Architectures for Deep Neural Networks"

If you have a graph background: [https://web.njit.edu/~ym329/dlg_book/](https://web.njit.edu/%7Eym329/dlg_book/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. The 4th mentioned references are very interesting.